# How to add query string parameter to FakeRequest in Play Framework 2.3?

Tags: rest, filter, routes, playframework-2.3

Here is the route corresponding to my controller method :

```
GET /my-resources controllers.MyResourceController.list(from: String ?= null, pageSize: Integer ?= null, sort: String ?= null)
```

I have no problem to use `from`, `pageSize` and `sort` parameters in my query but I can't find how to do with filters.
I'd like to be able to filter every field of the entity but I want to find a way to avoid adding each property of my entity in the route (i.e. : code, name, description...)

Kind of call that should work :

```
https://myapi.com/my-resources?sort=name,description&name=MyName&description=Blablabla
```

In my controller, I apply filters on my database query by browsing `request().queryString()`.
So my question is how to add a query string parameters in `FakeRequest` in order to test my controller ?
If you have a better approach to pass filters in the request, do not hesitate.

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Query string is parsed from the **URI**, that you provide to your FakeRequest, so you can create FakeRequest like this:

```
FakeRequest(GET, "/my-resources?sort=name,description&name=MyName&description=Blablabla")
```

And it would work fine.

Comment: It worked, thanks. I was using the noarg constructor of `FakeRequest`. Anyway, it would have been more practical to have a setter... Do you have any suggestion on a best practice to apply filters on a REST API with Play ?

Comment: We are doing it in standard way https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.6/ScalaHttpFilters :)

Comment: Actually I meant filters to filter an entity like name=Foo, beginning>12/29/2014 etc. ;)